# Directory for my LaTeX class and style files

Tags: installing

I have an Ubuntu installation and wanting to insert class and style files so that they will be picked up by texhash. Where do I put them?
My system denies me permission (is this a consequence of texlive or my configuration?) to add subfolders to texlive and texmf folders, and texhash does not seem to recognise the directory in which I stored them.
I have also tried to amend the ls-R file directory, but permission is denied.
Alternatively, how can I change the permissions on either creating subfolders or editing ls-R?

John

Comment: `~/texmf/tex/latex/foobar.sty`, then run `mktexlsr` or `texhash` as simple user (actually, this is not even necessary for `~/texmf`, in the default config on current Debian). Use the TeX Directory Structure for the layout of your `~/texmf/` (you can mimic the layout of `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist`, or whatever system TEXMF tree you have).

Comment: @frougon IIRC, it is discouraged to hash `~/texmf`, and as you already mentioned, it isn't necessary.

Comment: @Skillmon I'm always happy to take a few seconds to run a command that will later save me microseconds a few times. ;-)) (assuming my `ls-R` file in `~/texmf` is actually used...)

Comment: @frougon well, I'm happy to spend hours of my life optimising packages which are currently used by 0 users... :)

Comment: You can't directly make changes to your installation as your user doesn't have write permission to the folders TeX Live got installed in. That is a good thing security wise. You can still make changes by using for example `sudo` (but there is no reason to play with your `texmf-dist`, instead, play with `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local`, which needs to be hashed as well)

Comment: Actually, what I wanted to say in my first comment was `mktexlsr ~/texmf` (as unpriviledged user). But as we wrote, this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful suggestions. I don't have a directory /usr/share/texlive/texmf-local, and refused permission to create such a directory. I am accustomed to Windows, where I was quite comfortable about creating directories, and have migrated to Linux where I encounter this problem of permissions. Not familiar with  sudo, so may be I need to explore this further.